# Interact with jQuery dynamically loaded iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

By clicking on the X. I want to hide the `div` that houses my iFrame. I inserted the iFrame with jQuery. I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxc930xr/4/) with my example. Right now if I can just get "clicked" into the console when clicking on the X I'll be happy.

Here is my jQuery that inserts and tries to hid the div that contains my iFrame.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  if (document.location.pathname === '/account'){
  console.log("loaded up");
  $('body').append($.parseHTML(frame));
}

$('#fresh-credit-button').on('click', function(){
  console.log("clicked");
});

});
```

I don't have cross domain issues because I am using an appProxy thru Shopify.

Comment: you will be having cross-origin issues here, you can't have access with the elements inside an iframe with a different domain.

Comment: I'm actually using a proxy, that gets around the cross domain issue.. good thought though!

Comment: well, that's great then, you can access the element `iframe.contentWindow.document` or `iframe.contentDocument`. Can't create snippet because of cross-domain issues with jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this if you already fixed the cross-domain issue.

**Get the reference to that iframe:**

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src="https://test-4658.myshopify.com/apps/proxy/credit"]')
```

**Then from there do it like this below:**

```
var innerDoc = (iframe.contentDocument) ? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

**Then attach the onclick event**

```
var closeBtn = innerDoc.getElementById('fresh-credit-button');

closeBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
    //close div here
    //same idea when accessing the div element from the iframe
});
```

> This is only written in native JS, you can do it via jQuery if you want. I hope it helps you find a way in fixing from your end as I couldn't create a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... You could try streaming the website from jquery like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/uxc930xr/15/

```
$('#message').load('https://test-4658.myshopify.com/apps/proxy/credit');
```

Unfortunately this can't run on jsfiddle due to it blocking jquery html from other sources